# Same component used multiple times results in multiple API calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, rxjs

I've made an api call to fetch the logo, this is used multiple times on the same page.

```
export class LogoService {
```

logo$ = this.http.get(...).pipe(shareReplay(1));

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}

This works just fine, however what I get are multiple API calls that give me the same result every time I reuse this component. How can I get reduce this to only one API call no matter how many times I want to reuse it?

Answer (score 1):

You can either make the API call in your parent component, or use a dedicated service if your parents are not the same component.

```js
export class LogoService {

  logo$ = this.http.get(...).pipe(shareReplay(1));

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

Just subscribe to this `logo$` property and you should get all the info from the API call, that will be made just once.